# when using python sockets, is there any way for the client to receive data without sending any?

Tags: python, sockets, multiplayer

So I'm currently building a multiplayer python game with sockets, but I ran into some issues when putting the game on a global server (is that the right term?)

basically, once every loop, my game would run something like

```
reply = server.send("receive", "")
playerlist = reply
```

and then the reply would return a list of every players coordinates, and the client would set its own local list to the response

however, when I use a global server, the client cant send and receive information as fast, and as a result, the game becomes super chunky. The players basically teleport around the screen. When running the server on a local network, this doesn't seem to be a problem.

I was wondering if anyone knows a way for the server to just directly send information to the client, without the client having to ask every frame?

Comment: some servers use UDP instead of TCP to send it faster. As I remeber in old Doom they simply tried to predict positions and later confirm it with data from server.

Comment: if you will run other thread only with `recv` (probably with other port) then server may `send` data to this `recv` without waiting for `send` from client.

Comment: Could you give some details on how your protocol works?

Comment: basically my client sends "recieve" to the server, and the server sends a list back with every single players information, which the client then uses
there's some other functions that convert lists to strings or whatever but that's pretty much irrelevant

Comment: ty furas, ill need to try that soon